# Asterisk multiple IP registration

Tags: asterisk

I have Linux box with several IP addresses running Asterisk.

Is there a way to force asterisk to make trunk registrations from specific (not default) IP addresses? I need to connect 2 users from the same asterisk box to the same provider via different IPs.

Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

Comment: This question is off-topic for Stack Overflow as it is not about programming, within the scope as defined by the Help Center.

Answer (score 0):

You have use 3 trunks and source-based routing.

Asterisk will select interface from which packet have be send based on source-routing.

Answer (score 0):

Put Host="Client IP Address" in the sip peers. You need to create two different sip peers for two users.
You can use the trunk using pattern matchin/ dial plan.